# Url.Action: is there a workaround for a url that's too long?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Here's my Javascript function:

```
function myFunction() {
    var grid = $('#GridName').data('tGrid');
    var data = JSON.stringify(grid.data);

    var window = $('#Window').data('tWindow');
    window.content('<%= Resources.Global.Loading %>');
    window.contentUrl = '<%= Url.Action("MyMethod", "MyController") %>' + '?data=' + data;
    ...
}
```

It gets grid data, turns it into a string and sends it as a parameter to MyMethod.

Unfortunately, **data** is a very long string and this function doesn't work. I've tried sending substrings and there is indeed a cutoff point for the number of characters.

Is there a way around this limit, or a different way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you `POST` the data to the server, get the response, and then populate the result in whatever `tWindow` is instead of allowing it to load the URL itself?

Comment: (Out of inexperience) How would I go about doing that? My page and window have 2 different ViewModels

Comment: You would use AJAX to post to that Url, and then in a response callback you would: (1) capture the view HTML, and (2) try replacing the window HTML using `window.content(response);`. There are many tutorials online for using AJAX (natively, or through a library like jQuery), so I'll leave that as an excercise for you. Why would this work? `POST` is allowed to submit more data to the server than what you can send via `GET` (URL parameters are part of the `GET` request, `POST` encodes the data as part of the request headers).

Comment: It worked! Thanks again Cory

Comment: No problem. I've copied my comment into an answer. If it helped you find a solution, please accept it by clicking the green checkbox to the left of the answer. Also, welcome to [so]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy of my comment from above:

You could use AJAX to `POST` to that URL, and then in a response callback you could: (1) capture the view HTML, and (2) try replacing the window HTML using `window.content(response);`.

There are many tutorials online for using AJAX (natively, or through a library like jQuery), so I'll leave that as an excercise for you.

Why would this work? Form submissions via `POST` are normally allowed to submit more data to the server than what you can send in a URL via `GET` (URL parameters are part of the GET request, whereas `POST` encodes the data as part of the request headers).

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
function myFunction() {
    var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
    var data = JSON.stringify(grid.data);

    var window = $('#Window').data('tWindow');
    window.content('<%= Resources.Global.Loading %>');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        cache: false,
        url: '<%= Url.Action("MyMethod", "MyController") %>',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { data: data },
        success: function (e) {
            window.content(e);
        }
    });

    ...
    }
```